# BigQuery - extract the most used tables

Tags: google-bigquery, audit

I'm using the Google BigQuery and looking on the default `audit` dataset.
I know that this dataset contains various data about the queries the users are running.

I wondered if I can write a query that will show me the MOST USED tables over my project (lets say for the last 30 days)?

Output example:

```
table_1_name: 5000 queries
table_2_name: 4000 queries
table_3_name: 2000 queries
```

and so on...

Answer (score 4):

Adding the answer from Tamir Klein, here's the query you can use:

```
SELECT
job_id,
creation_time,
referenced_tables.dataset_id,
referenced_tables.table_id
FROM `your-project-name`.`your-region`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT,
UNNEST(referenced_tables) AS referenced_tables
WHERE job_type = 'QUERY' 
AND DATE(creation_time) >= DATE_SUB(DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

That will give you list of jobs and the reference tables used in all your query jobs in the past 30 days.

Then you can aggregate them by dataset_id and table_id:

```
SELECT
dataset_id,
table_id,
COUNT(DISTINCT job_id) AS total_jobs
FROM referenced_table_list
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

and add conditions as you wish, e.g. WHERE dataset_id = 'audit'.
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can use BigQuery [Jobs.list](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/list) to get all the Jobs you executed.
Inside the response, there is an array, referencedTables, which tells you which tables where used in the Job

```
"referencedTables": [
           {
              "projectId": string,
              "datasetId": string,
              "tableId": string
            }
]
```

You can now collect this information into a destination table or other storage to get the metadata you are looking for

Comment: You can find this data for query responses in the `data_access` logs table using the `protopayload_auditlog.servicedata_v1_bigquery.jobQueryResponse.job.jobStatistics.referencedTables` field.